# Are you a human being?

Tags: bug, captcha

I was presented by this while trying to search from my home computer on superuser without being signed-in.

Since I could not answer a CAPTCHA; here is my proof:

[image]

I hope I the confusion is now cleared, an you will not confuse me for a robot anymore. Thanks.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you're saying you got the captcha page but no captcha appeared?

Comment: If you go to http://superuser.com/captcha can you see the captcha?

Comment: Being somewhat human I am having a hard time understanding what it is that you are trying to say? Although I am sure the machine registered something from your question :-)

Comment: What browser and do you have any extensions running?

Comment: [Works for me](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ALKH2.png). The nocaptchas are rendered by a third party script though, it seems [they've been having some issues lately](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/13658/captcha-has-no-submit-button).

Comment: Can I close this as 'primarily opinion-based'? I see no clear proof the poster is actually human ;)